# How can I have the name of my entity instead of the id in the related tables

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm creating a project on CakePHP 3.x where I'm quite new. I'm having trouble with the hasMany related tables to get the name of my entities instead of their ids.

I'm coming from CakePHP 2.x where I used an `App::import('controller', array('Users')` but in the view to retrieve all data to display instead of the ids, which is said to be a bad practice. And I wouldn't like to have any code violation in my new code. Can anybody help me? here is the code :

```
public function view($id = null)
{     
     $this->loadModel('Users');
     $relatedUser = $this->Users->find()
         ->select(['Users.id', 'Users.email'])
         ->where(['Users.id'=>$id]);
     $program = $this->Programs->get($id, [
         'contain' => ['Users', 'ProgramSteps', 'Workshops']
     ]);

     $this->set(compact('program', 'users'));
     $this->set('_serialize', ['ast', 'relatedUser']);
}
```

I expect to get the user's email in the relatedUsers of the program table but the actual output is:

```
Notice (8): Trying to get property 'user_email' of non-object [APP/Template\Asts\view.ctp, line 601].
```

Really need help

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you post the result of `debug($relatedUser)`, when placed at the end of the controller action? I suspect the query object simply isn't executed.

Comment: here is the result I get in running the debug($relatedUser) Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=C:\xampp\htdocs\Apps\apc-crud\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php line=952 [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 48]
Code Context
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emit() - CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 48
Cake\Http\Server::emit() - CORE\src\Http\Server.php, line 141
[main] - ROOT\webroot\index.php, line 40

Comment: No, that is not the debug result. You are citing a warning produced from the page. Please give the debug result.

Comment: object(Cake\ORM\Query) {

 '(help)' => 'This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.',
 'sql' => 'SELECT Users.id AS `Users__id`, Users.email AS `Users__email` FROM users Users WHERE Users.id = :c0',
 'params' => [
  ':c0' => [
   'value' => '1',
   'type' => 'integer',
   'placeholder' => 'c0'
  ]
 ],
 'defaultTypes' => [
  'Users__id' => 'integer',
  'Users.id' => 'integer',
  'id' => 'integer',
  'Users__slug' => 'string',
  'Users__email' => 'string',
  'Users.email' => 'string',
  'email' => 'string',
  'Users__password' => 'string'
  
 ],

Answer (score 0):

You've asked it to serialize the `relatedUser` variable, but that's for JSON and XML views. You haven't actually `set` the `relatedUser` variable for the view:

```
$this->set(compact('program', 'users', 'relatedUser'));
```

Also, you're setting the `$users` variable here, but it's never been initialized.

Comment: Ok, Sorry, I have been out for a while; I can understand, I'll check with the changes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Greg's answers, the variable `$relateduser` is still a query object, meaning that trying to access the `email` property will fail. The query still needs to be executed first.

You can change the query to:

```
 $relatedUser = $this->Users->find()
     ->select(['Users.id', 'Users.email'])
     ->where(['Users.id' => $id])
     ->first();
```

Now the query is executed and the only the first entry is returned.

There is are a number of ways to get a query to execute, a lot of them are implicit is use. See:

- [**Cookbook > Retrieving Data & Results Sets**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html)

Comment: I get a syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) with the ->first();

Comment: That's weird. Pretty sure the syntax in my post is correct. Maybe check it again and look at the link I attached to very it.

Comment: Useful link, thank you Roberto, that solved my problem. Now I'm using loadModel but in a cell which seems to be a much better way.

Comment: Cool. Yes, cells provide an excellent way of storing general logic. Could you select a best answer, or a summarising answer by yourself?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a quite new user of this site, so I'll maybe need some help for that also